# Convertir mayusculas a minisculas y viceversa en un fichero

Tags: c

Necesito leer la información de un fichero y pasar las mayúsculas a minúsculas y viceversa pero no se como poner los parámetros de toupper usando una matriz este es mi código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fich1,*fich2;
    char cadena[100][100];
    int n=0,i=0;
    fich1=fopen("fichero1.txt","r");
    fich2=fopen("fichero2.txt","w");

    if(fich1==NULL)
    {
        perror("Error al abrir el fichero");
    }

    while(fgets(cadena[n],100,fich1))
    {
        cadena[n][i]=toupper(cadena[n][i]);
        n++;
        i++;
        fputs(cadena[n],fich2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica acá:

```
while(fgets(cadena[n],100,fich1))
{
  cadena[n][i]=toupper(cadena[n][i]);
  n++;
  i++;
  fputs(cadena[n],fich2);
}
```

Debes recorrer las columnas de cada fila de la matriz "cadena", de lo contrario, nunca estarías llenando los caracteres en cada fila (que vendría ser la cadena).
Además de eso, la variable contadora "n" debe ser incrementada después de fputs, o sino, no estarías agregando nada al fichero.
Solución:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    FILE *fich1, *fich2;
    char cadena[100][100];
    int n=0,i=0;
    size_t len;
    fich1=fopen("fichero1.txt","r");
    fich2=fopen("fichero2.txt","w");
    if(fich1==NULL || fich2 == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error al abrir el fichero");
    }

    while(fgets(cadena[n],100,fich1))
    {
        //Obtenemos la longitud de la cadena para recorrer caracter x caracter.
        len = strlen(cadena[n]);
        for(i = 0; i != len; ++i)
            cadena[n][i]=toupper(cadena[n][i]);
        //printf("%s\n", cadena[n]); 

        fputs(cadena[n], fich2);
        n++;
    }
    //Hay que cerrar los archivos (liberar recursos)
    fclose(fich1);
    fclose(fich2);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> No se como poner los parámetros de `toupper` usando una matriz.

Es normal que no sepas, ya que [`toupper`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) no trabaja con matrices:

> #### `toupper`
>
> *Definida en la cabecera `<ctype.h>`*
>
> ```
> int toupper( int ch );
> ```
>
> Convierte el carácter proporcionado a mayúsculas siguiendo las reglas de conversión definidas en el local de C instalado. En el local de C por defecto, las siguientes letras minúsculas abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz se reemplazan por sus respectivas letras ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.

Puedes ver que `toupper` recibe un sólo parámetro de tipo entero (`int`), no una matriz.

---

Así que lo que deberías hacer es:

1. Leer el archivo de origen carácter a carácter (no *cadena* a *cadena*).
2. Transformar el carácter.
3. Guardar el carácter transformado en el archivo de destino.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *entrada = fopen("fichero1.txt", "r");
    FILE *salida = fopen("fichero2.txt", "w");

    char caracter;

    while (fgets(&caracter, 1, entrada))
    {
        fprintf(salida, "%c", isupper(caracter) ? tolower(caracter): toupper(caracter));
    }

    fclose(entrada);
    fclose(salida);

    return 0;
}
```